# MWAA (2.8.1) Cannot install snowflake-connector-python

Tags: amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, airflow, mwaa

I am encountering difficulties installing the snowflake-connector-python package in my AWS Managed Workflows for Apache Airflow (MWAA) private web server environment. When attempting to install the package, I receive the following error message:

The conflict is caused by:
The user requested snowflake-connector-python==3.6.0
The user requested (constraint) snowflake-connector-python==3.6.0

To provide some context, I have included the snowflake-connector-python wheel file (snowflake_connector_python-3.6.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64) in my plugins.zip file, which I assume should install the package. However, it's not the case.

Please advise on how to proceed with resolving this issue and successfully installing the snowflake-connector-python package in my MWAA private web server environment. Any insights or suggestions from the community would be highly appreciated.

Comment: As taehoka mentioned correctly, you might have the wrong packages (python version!) in your zip file? Maybe you can verify if that solves your problem?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mwaa/latest/userguide/airflow-versions.html#airflow-versions-image

The MWAA 2.8.1 is using python 3.11.

Would you try it with snowflake_connector_python-3.6.0-cp311-cp311-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64?

"cp311" not "cp310".

Comment: thank you. that's correct. It worked fine after downloading python3.11 compatible wheel files